# Compound Interest Problems:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A Sum of Rs.13,360 was borrowed at 8[3/4] % per annum compound interest and paid back in two years in two equal annual installments . what was the amount of each installment?

I have tried:

Let each installment be x

```
(present worth of X due 1 yr hence) + (Present worth of rs x due 2 year hence) = 13360

x/(1+ 35/400) + x/(1+35/400)^2 =13360
```

I have got the Answer **x = 7369**

This is correct Answer

**It is taking Large amount of steps in calculationg the answer, is there any alternate way to find out the answer for these type of sums, or shortcut manner , please anyone guide me answer**

```
Generally how to approach these type of Installment sums,anyone Guide me the Answer
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's start with the equation that you provided

$$\frac{x}{1+\frac{35}{400}}+\frac{x}{(1+\frac{35}{400})^2} = 13360$$
$$x\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{35}{400}}+x\cdot\frac{1}{(1+\frac{35}{400})^2} = 13360$$
$$x\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{35}{400}}+x\cdot\bigg(\frac{1}{1+\frac{35}{400}}\bigg)^2 = 13360$$

To simplify things, lets represent $1/(1+35/400)$ symbolically as $t$
$$x t+x t^2 = 13360$$
$$x(t+t^2) = 13360$$
Further suppose that instead of being  paid back over two years, it was paid back over ten years. Then the equation would be
$$x(t+t^2+t^3+t^4+t^5+t^6+t^7+t^8+t^9+t^{10}) = 13360$$

Can you find a way of simplifying this expression?

If the interest rate $i$ equals $35/400$, how would you express $t$ in terms of $i$?